# Can interpreter make a mistake?

Tags: java, c++

Like in any programming languages (Like Java or C++), can an interpertor make a mistake? I am not talking about compile time error, logic error, or runtime error. I am talking about `50 + 21` printing not `71` but `72` or something like that like a human. This is kind of a weird question though...

Comment: Compilers will not do mistakes unless it is programmed(mistakenly) to do so by the creator of the compiler

Comment: Interpreters and compilers are made by humans, and do have bugs. Well-tested and well-maintained interpreters/compilers have less bugs (and would never become famous if they still did errors of that magnitude -- except maybe PHP, which was horribly buggy even when it was already popular).

Comment: A case in point: I can make in less than 10 minutes a C++ interpreter which will prints `7` as a result of any valid C++ program you feed it. Bonus: even invalid C++ programs would be interpreted to print `7`. Great, eh? Granted, nobody would ever use it, because it would be the worst C++ interpreter ever. The famous compilers like `clang` or `g++` don't print `7` unless your C++ code actually tells it to.

Comment: I encountered one compiler ten, twelve years back that generated horribly wrong instructions when the code performed 64 bit arithmetic in a return statement. So yes.

Answer (score 5):

Any language implementation (i.e. compiler or interpreter) is a program itself, coded the same way as any other program. Of course it could make mistakes, in the same way as mistakes found in any other programs. It could range from wrong parsing logic, wrong code generation, wrong optimization, etc. Most if not all of them provide public bug tracking tool, for which you can report and view errors at many different levels (sometimes even user's own error is reported there, too).

Comment: Compilers are well tested software. Bugs in them are much less probable then bugs in software being developed. So if you encounter bug in your application, then it remains bug in YOUR application, unless you investigate it thoroughly and prove that it is a compiler issue.

Comment: Doesn't diminish the chance for bugs to exist, especially since there's no guarantee if all implementations are well tested, it's still up to the maintainers. Regressions are not uncommon, especially during development. If you like to push implementations to their limit (e.g. trying new features, bootstrap them with different optimization level, etc.), you will encounter bugs quite often like I do.

Answer (score -1):

No the compiler will always provide the correct answer, as long as your logic is correct. You wouldn't have your calculator in class give you the wrong answer if you entered the correct numbers. The same idea applies here. Sometimes it can see that way when you have very long complicated programs, but there is always an error or case you didn't see.

Comment: So you've never encountered a compiler bug?